# Swagger UI incorrectly displays properties in lower-case for XML requests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a basic .NET 6 web API project with Swagger and I have a dummy HttpPost endpoint that should accept both JSON and XML. As far as I see, model bindings for JSON are case insensitive but for XML it's not, and here comes my problem.

In Program.cs I have the following settings for XML serialization:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
});
```

My endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<DummyDto> PostDummyData(DummyDto dummyDto)
{
   return await Task.FromResult(dummyDto);
}
```

My DTO:

```
public class DummyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Default example in Swagger UI for application/xml and text/xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DummyDto>
    <id>0</id>
    <name>string</name>
</DummyDto>
```

As you can see my class name is correct, but my properties are lowercase by default and after a long search I still have no idea how to display my property attributes correctly, or how to disable case sensitivity for XML model binding.

By adding the [XmlElement] attribute to the properties I was able to make it work with lowercase, but I don't like this workaround. Is there any generic solution that I could use for this problem?

Comment: Its a default behavior of swagger.

Comment: Probably related? https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/712

Answer (score 1):

By default Web API serializes the fields of types that have a [Serializable] attribute (e.g. Version).

You can add this line of code in Program.cs to stop the Web API from doing this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().
                AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                });
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: what could it be in case of `.AddNewtonsoftJson`?