# C# WebAPI Swagger changing all property names to lowercase

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API using SwaggerUI. When my methods use a class for a parameter, it changes all of its properties to lowercase.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Wanna say it's simply following JSON notation and there is no practical way to change that.

Comment: JSON notation doesn't require the capitialization to be lower. JSON is case sensitive, but that is not the same thing.

Comment: See if any of these Q&As answer your question: [Is it possible to give input model properties different names in the Swagger UI, without using FromQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57477903/113116), [Web API serialize properties starting from lowercase letter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22130431/113116), [Swagger UI incorrectly displays properties in lower-case for XML requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73498138/113116), [API Json response to C# Object with capital case properties first letter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59281901/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [PascalCase formatting instead of the default camelCase formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-systemtextjson-based-formatters-2)

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute to make it uppercase. For example:
[image]
[image]
You can see that the key turns into uppercase with this attribute.